# FTP bind to a specific interface

Tags: linux, ftp

Do you know how to bind the ftp command to use one of my specific interface?

Comment: Usually, you can configure the `ftpd` server to use one particular interface (or IP address). Some `ftp` clients (like `ncftp`) are also highly configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a socket "bind()"?

SO_BINDTODEVICE is one option:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/setsockoptman.html

As far as a "non-programming-system-administration" answer - that depends on your FTP server and your environment.

Here is a link that suggests vsftpd can be bound to a specific interface via xinet configuration:

http://www.linuxfocus.org/English/July2004/article341.shtml

Comment: I need to use the Net::FTP module of perl